# Do you need to put your product category pages link in the nav menu bar for better SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, links, navigation

Our current product category pages are not in our nav menu and can only be reached via filters on our product page.

Does having direct links from the nav menu to the product category pages improve their SEO?

I know that there are other factors to consider for having a better SEO but I feel that this is the only missing step that we haven't done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

By linking to categories from the main navigation, every page links to every category. This indicates the importance of those pages, provides better user experience, provides many more paths for search engine crawlers, and so on… in short, better for performance all-round, including SEO.

Comment: That's what I thought also. Now, it's time for us to redesign the nav menus. Thanks.